# Swap childs of every node at depth N in a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

Say we have this tree, and we are going to perform a swap at depth 2:

```
    1                  1  
   / \                / \ 
  2   3   [s]  ->    2   3
   \   \            /   / 
    4   5          4   5
```

I'm trying to write a function that does just that:

```
public void swap(TreeNode node, int[] swaps, int i, int arraySize, int depth) {
        if(arraySize == 0) return;

        if(depth < swaps[i]) {
            swap(node, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
        }

        if(depth == swaps[i]) {
            TreeNode temp = node.left;
            node.left = node.right;
            node.right = temp;

            swap(node.left, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
            swap(node.right, swaps, i+1, arraySize-1, depth+1);
        }

    }
```

When I run the do a inorder traversal of tree above before and after calling the method, I get the same result:

```
2 4 1 3 5
```

I should be getting

```
4 2 1 5 3
```

Comment: Okay now i understand your previous question a lot better. But one more question, what is in `swaps` array?

Comment: @Smith_61 hey again :) It can be multiple swaps involved, and all the different depths are stored in that array. In that specific example: the array would just contain 2.

Comment: Okay so the `swaps` array contains all the different levels you want to swap at. So if you wanted to swap, say levels 2, 4, 7, it would contain just those numbers in increasing order?

Comment: @Smith_61 yes. that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are going after then,

```
public void swap( TreeNode node, int depth, int[ ] sDepths, int sI ) {
    if( node == null || sI >= sDepths.length ) return;
    if( depth == sDepths[ sI ] ) {
        TreeNode tmp = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = tmp;
        sI++;
    }
    swap( node.left, depth + 1, sDepths, sI );
    swap( node.right, depth + 1, sDepths, sI );
}
```

Explanation:

First it verifies that we didn't walk off the tree and that there are more swaps to perform. Then it checks if the current depth needs to be swapped. If it does we swap and increment the index into the swaps array. Then we repeat on it's children.

This requires `sDepth` to be in increasing order and initial call would be like `swap( root, 0, sDepths, 0 )`

Comment: Thank for your effort, but this gives me the same answer as I'm getting: `2 4 1 3 5 `

Comment: I used zero indexing here,  so the root is a depth zero where you had root at depth 1. You'll need to add one to starting depth or decrement 1 from each of your splitting depths